# Count number of non empty columns and select the one which is non blank - python

Tags: pandas, string, sum

I am searching for values in possible columns.  I am able to find where there are matches.  My challenge then becomes how to select the non empty columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {"Search1":["one_two","two_ten", "five_ten"],
        "Search2":["three_four","one_four","two_twelve"],
        "FindMe":["three","one","nine"],
        "FindMe2":["five","two","nine"]}
df =pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Found1"] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: str(x.FindMe) in str(x.Search1), axis =1) ==1, df.Search1,
                np.where(df.apply(lambda x: str(x.FindMe) in str(x.Search2), axis =1) ==1, df.Search2,""))

df["Found2"] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: str(x.FindMe2) in str(x.Search1), axis =1) ==1, df.Search1,
                np.where(df.apply(lambda x: str(x.FindMe2) in str(x.Search2), axis =1) ==1, df.Search2,""))
#sum of founds
df["Want_Sum"] = [1,2,0]

#return value where not blank
#second is blank because there are two options in Found 1 and Found2
df["Value_of_Found"] = ["three_four", "", ""]

print(df)
```

I would want to sum the non empty columns of Found1 and Found2, and where this equals 1, take the column that is filled.

I have posted another question about how I am writing my Found1 code.

Comment: updated as requested.  Clearer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to then you can use nested `np.where()`:

```
np.where((df['Found1'].str.len() > 0) ^ (df['Found2'].str.len() > 0), \
         np.where((df['Found1'].str.len() > 0), df['Found1'], df['Found2'] ), '' )
```

Result:

```
array(['three_four', '', ''], dtype=object)
```

You could assign to a column

```
df['Filled'] = np.where(...)
```

**Here are more details on how this works.**

`np.where()` is the fundamental component of this answer.  It returns one of two different values depending on a condition.  The first one is returned if the condition is true the second value is returned if the condiiton is false.

```
np.where(condition, value-if-true, value-if-false)
```

What this answer contains is a nested `np.where()` statement.  That is another `np.where()` replaces the value-if-true above.

```
np.where(condition, np.where(condition, value-if-true, value-if-false), value-if-false)
```

The first condition checks to see if the lengths of Found1 and Found2 are different using exclusive or logic.

```
(df['Found1'].str.len() > 0) ^ (df['Found2'].str.len() > 0)
```

If they are different then that means we need to pick the one that is len > 0 via the nested `np.where()`:

```
np.where((df['Found1'].str.len() > 0), df['Found1'], df['Found2'] )
```

Comment: This works really well... but I don't understand why.  I need to expand this to 9 columns.  Can you explain it to me so I can use it?

Comment: I will update my answer to explain how it works.  Then to expand - For two columns - Found1 and Found2 - if Found1 is empty then fill with Found2 - and the other way around.  How would the fill algorithm work if you had 9 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that can be extended easily to several columns. use `filter` with `regex='Found\d'` to select all the columns Found in your dataframe. check not equal (`ne`) to the empty string and `sum` along the columns to get the Want_Sum column. For the Value_of_Found column only where the sum is 1, then you can do `np.where` the Want_Sum is equal to 1, get the `max` along columns Found else empty string.

```
df['Want_Sum'] = df.filter(regex='Found\d').ne('').sum(axis=1)
df["Value_of_Found"] = np.where(df['Want_Sum'].eq(1), 
                                df.filter(regex='Found\d').max(axis=1), 
                                '')
print(df)
    Search1     Search2 FindMe FindMe2      Found1   Found2  Want_Sum  \
0   one_two  three_four  three    five  three_four                  1   
1   two_ten    one_four    one     two    one_four  two_ten         2   
2  five_ten  two_twelve   nine    nine                              0   

  Value_of_Found  
0     three_four  
1                 
2
```